# Bootloader install failed dual boot

Tags: bootloader

"Sorry, an error occured and it was not possible to install the bootloader at the specified location" After I bought I brand new 1tb HHD to install Ubuntu on. Any ideas?  (Dual booting with Windows 10)

Comment: Are you doing something special? Buying a disk usually doesn't triggers bootloader errors, ... Have you tried installing your bootloader on the "other" disk?

Comment: Installing in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? Is drive partitioned MBR or gpt. If Windows 10 pre-installed it will be UEFI/gpt and then best to have Ubuntu in UEFI mode on gpt partitioned drive. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace & http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

This issue has brought misery and woe to many, myself included. The causes and solutions seem to vary slightly. The solution I found is not quite ideal but it ended up working.

In my case, I was able to find success after using [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to try to install the bootloader again. I ran boot-repair in the non-UEFI Ubuntu from the LiveUSB instead of from the UEFI version. I have a feeling similar success is possible after making an EFI partition but I was a little wary after I ran into a lot of trouble in this adventure. At one point my computer kept freezing at the BIOS splash screen. I think it was because Windows tries to "repair" the LiveUSB disk which puts it in a state that my EFI/BIOS had trouble with.

My Windows 10 is on a dynamic disk and I learned that the bootloader wasn't going to be able to be installed there. However, boot-repair was able to install it onto the disk that Ubuntu is on, which is what I was trying to do with the installer both when it first asked about the disks and later in that error window.

With this setup, I have to select the disk I installed Ubuntu on in the BIOS menu when the computer starts up. Grub shows up when I select the disk with Ubuntu and I'm able to boot into the OS, however I'm not able to get into Windows from any of the two selections it shows. Instead, I have to use the BIOS menu to select the disk that has Windows. This works alright, but I might try the UEFI boot solution when I'm feeling adventurous again.